# Recursively search database to fill a list

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, search, tree

I have a list of some items which are related to each other as "parent" and "child", for example:

```
> Math
-> Trigonometry
--> Angles
--> Sin, cosin and tangent
-> Calculus
(...)
> Biology
```

And this goes on. I made it on the database with a "super" column which indicates the parent id when it's applicable, otherwise it's 0.

I have absolutely no idea on how to find all levels and apply them to a nested (one inside another?) list on HTML. There is no depth limit.

If any information is needed, just ask. I'm using PHP 5.5 with CodeIgniter framework. Pseudocode/algorithm should be enough for me, but if you feel like, PHP code would be nice.

Comment: This link might help: http://www.ibase.ru/devinfo/DBMSTrees/sqltrees.html

Comment: I have an idea on how to store the data, but I can't think on how to retrieve it later maintaining hierarchy, you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use recursion if your tree will have unlimited levels, and if you're going to have lots of items in the tree, you'll need to consider memory usage as you build and render the tree.

Keeping that in mind, I solved a similar problem recently with the following pattern: load the tree, then render the tree.

Starting with the render() method, you'll get all of the data for your tree loaded up. You'll start with the parent nodes and get the parents children. get_children() has a recursive option to get the childrens' children. Once the data is loaded, then render the data. Start with rendering the top level nodes, and then recursively for the children and children's children.

You'll need to fill in the parts to actually grab the data from your data source, but here's a start:

```
<?php

class Tree
{
    var $tree = array();

    function render()
    {
        $this->tree = $this->load();
        $html = ''; // use your favorite templating system to generate the html

        foreach ($this->tree as $parent_node)
        {
            $html .= $this->render_node($parent_node);
        }

        return $html;
    }

    function render_node($parent_node,$recursive=true)
    {
        // use your favorite templating system to generate the html
        $html = '<ul><li>' . $parent_node->name;
        $html .= '<ul>';
        foreach ($parent_node->children as $child)
        {
            $html .= '<li>' . $child->name;
            if ($recursive === true)
            {
                $html .= $this->render_node($child,$recursive);
            }
            $html .= '</li>';
        }
        $html .= '</ul>';        
        $html .= '</li></ul>';

        return $html;
    }

    function load_tree()
    {
        $parents = $this->get_tree_parents();
        foreach ($parents as $parent)
        {
            $parent->children = $this->get_children($parent);
        }

        $this->tree = $parents;
    }

    function get_tree_parents()
    {
        // find all top level nodes in the tree
        return $parent_nodes;
    }

    function get_children($parent,$recursive=true)
    {
        // find all child nodes of the $parent
        $children = array(/*...*/);

        if ($recursive === true)
        {
            foreach ($children as $child)
            {
                $child->children = $this->get_children($child,$recursive);
            }
        }

        return $children;
    }
}
```

And to run something like this, you'd just need:

```
<?php

$tree = new Tree();
echo $tree->render();
```

There are all sorts of optimizations you can make depending on your specific use case. If you have a huge tree, you'll probably need to use ajax to only load data on the client as needed. You can add parameters to the data and rendering methods to load on specific branches of the tree as requested.

Comment: Hmm well thought, loading dynamically using ajax seems nice. I will try this.

Comment: @ranisalt great, I hope it helps. The two main things you'll need to add for handling ajax is adding a node_parent_id when loading the tree. That way you can load a specific subtree using starting with whatever node needs to be loaded. You'll also want to not use recursion on the requests so that it'll only load the exact subtree the user clicked on.

Comment: I actually load dynamically what user clicks on and then I change the click event listener to a hide or show toggle :P this way, I load it and keep on the document, instead of reloading every time! I also didn't need to render the whole tree. Thanks!

Comment: @ranisalt ok great, that makes sense. In my use case I had tens of thousands of items, so loading them all initially and toggling on the display client-side was way too slow, so I had to go the full ajax'd route.